# Android admob requests keep going up

Tags: java, android, admob

Firstly, I am new to admob and this is my very first app that includes ads from admob.
Just a simple question which I am not too sure about.
I have uploaded my first app today and I have been refreshing the admob control panel? page every half an hour or so an the number of ad requests keep going up.
I don't think I have anyone who has even downloaded the app and was wondering why it is going up and if that is a good or bad thing.
Thanks.

Comment: If you're using the Android Market then http://market.android.com/publish/Home will tell you how many people have downloaded your app. Though it's not up to the minute, it should give you a good idea of how many users you have.

Comment: I've been checking both since I was very anxious to see how this all works with admob but it's starting to really confuse me since admob ad requests keep rising and so far I have two test devices which have the app and I don't see how these two could possible request over hundreds of times. And I have not advertised my app at all so what's with all the ad requests? Or is that a normal figure to be seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good thing because it means people are downloading and using your app. The data is refreshed on the Android publish page only once a day or so, so there may be many downloads but you won't see how many till maybe tomorrow or day after.

Comment: Ah, so it's a good thing. I was thinking it was bad to have so many requests from so few devices. =/